# TFS 2015 build server with git line endings

Tags: git, tfs, build

We use TFS 2015 with GIT and Team Foundation Build 2015 as Build definition. The Sources are in C/C++.
On the Build Server I'm facing a line ending problem.

On the developers PC (Microsoft Windows 7) the *core.autocrlf=true* is set. The line endings are always CRLF which is ok.

On the Build Server (Microsoft Server 2012 R2) the same *core.autocrlf=true* is set. If I get the sources on the Build Server on the command line (git version 2.7.2.windows.1) everything is ok and all source files has CRLF as line ending. 
But if the Build definition (e.g. for continuous integration) gets the sources, the line endings are always LF.

**Question:**
Where can I set the *core.autocrlf=true* for the Build definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and the solution.

The setting `core.autocrlf true` is correct for my environment. But the Build Server starts the Build with a different user as I was logged in to do the check of the settings.

**Solution:** Make sure the all users on the Build server has the same setting. 
I set an Environment System Variable `HOME` to the directory `C:\GitHome`. Within this directory the file `.gitconfig` is placed with the correct setting.
This works for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using vNext build. Get Source is a automatic step, we can't set or modify this step.

Just have a quick test, set core.autocrlf to `True` with command `git config --global core.autocrlf true`. Then run vNext build, the source will be checked out to `%agent%\_work\xx\s`. After that, under this working folder, run command `git config --list`, you'll see `core.autocrlf=true`. Get-source step doesn't change the core.autocrlf. You may try with this way.

[This article](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) provides more information on how to deal with line endings.

Comment: Correct, I am using vNext build. Good to know we can't change anything on the set Get Sources step. I will do some testing regarding the setting of core.autocrlf.